# What is a process for recovering a failed master from a slave with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.5 . For lack of better instructions anywhere else, I've configured a master-slave replication mechanism by following instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).

The missing steps to make it work where:

- On both master and slave: set wal_keep_segments = 8
- Restart master before proceeding with the slave
- Do not use rsync to transfer files from master to slave. Use a command like this from the slave:

```
pg_basebackup -h masterHostName -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main --username=rep —-password
```

Other than that, the process works. I am able to write into master, and I see  changes reflected in the slave.

Now, my question is this. Suppose master experiences a hardware failure and I am forced to turn the read-only slave into a read-write master. A few days later I get a replacement machine for the one that failed. How do I recover the failed machine ? Do I turn it into a new slave ?

Advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you'll need to completely setup the former master as a new slave, just like you did for the first slave.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail